# NPM shrinkwrap in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

What happens when you do `npm install` in a dev environment on a project that has both a `package.json` and a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file?
Will it ignore the shrinkwrap and use `package.json` for everything or just for the dev dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any files added to the production dependencies in  `package.json` will be ignored if they are not in the `npm-shrinkwrap.json`. Vis-à-vis: running `npm install` with `foo-package` added to the production dependency list **will not** install `foo-package`.

Not so for devDependancies.

Running `npm install` with `foo-package` added to the devDependency list **will** install `foo-package` even if it is not found in the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file.

Fun.

Node: v4.2.4

NPM: 2.14.12